# Partial specialization does not use any of its template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I'm trying to implement tuples with template metaprogramming, but am having problems with the indexing function `get`. The implementation of `Tuple` type is this:

```
template<typename A, typename... B>
class Tuple : Tuple<B...> {
    private:
        A val;
    public:
        using Base = Tuple<B...>;
        Base* base() {
            return static_cast<Base*>(this);
        }
        const Base* base() const {
            return static_cast<const Base*>(this);
        }
        Tuple(A a, B... b): Base(b...), val(a) { }
        A first() {
            return val;
        }
};

template<class A>
class Tuple<A> {
    private:
        A val;
    public:
        Tuple(A a): val{a} {}
        A first() {
            return val;
        }
};
```

The implementation of `get` structure is:

```
template<int N, class... A>
struct get {
    select<N,A...> operator()(Tuple<A...> t) {
        return get<N-1>()(t.base());
    }
};

template<class R, class... A>
struct get<0> {
    R operator()(Tuple<R, A...> t) {
        return t.first();
    }
};
```

This is the error compiler is giving me:

```
tuple.cpp:53:8: error: partial specialization of 'get' does not use any of its template parameters
struct get<0> {
       ^
1 error generated.
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I correct it?

Note: `select<N,A...>` is a type function which selects type at Nth index from `A`.

Comment: I think you can resolve it if you simply change `template <class R, class ... A>` to `template <>` and change `Tuple<R, A...>` to `Tuple<0>`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to partial specialize `get` as follows

```
template<class R, class... A>
struct get<0, R, A...> {
    R operator()(Tuple<R, A...> t) {
        return t.first();
    }
};
```

I mean... `get<0, R, A...>`, not `get<0>`

But you have also to modify the main `get` to call the following call with the correct type list, so

```
template<int N, typename A0, typename ... As>
struct get {
    auto operator()(Tuple<A0, As...> t) {
        return get<N-1, As...>()(t.base());
    }
};
```

Otherwise you can also demand the types management to a template version of the `operator()` and maintain only the `int N` value for `get`

```
template <int N>
struct get
 {
   template <typename Tpl>
   auto operator() (Tpl t)
      -> decltype( get<N-1>()(t.base()) )
    { return get<N-1>()(t.base()); }
 };

template<>
struct get<0>
 {
   template <typename Tpl>
   auto operator() (Tpl t)
      -> decltype ( t.first() )
    { return t.first(); }
 };
```

Starting from C++14 you can avoid the `decltype()` part.

Off topic suggestion: avoid the use of names that can collide with `std` namespace names.

Maybe `myGet` and `myTuple` instead of `get` and `Tuple`.

Otherwise you can put all in a personal namespace (so `myNs::get` and `myNs::Tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `get`'s primary template is:

```
template<int N, class... A>
struct get{ ... };
```

your `get`'s partial specialization is:

```
template<class R, class... A>
struct get<0>{ ... };
```

The specialization is receiving a single template argument, i.e.: `0`, but the primary template above takes two template parameters:

- the non-type template parameter `N`.
- the variadic type parameter `A`.

Besides, how can `R` be deduced?

---

Specializing `get` instead as:

```
template<class R, class... A>
struct get<0, R, A...>{ ... };
```

will make possible `R` to be deduced: it will be deduced to the type of the first element of the passed variadic argument. For example, in:

```
get<0, int, float, double> foo;
```

`R` will be deduced to `int`.